# How do i get the details of the max of a count?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, max

I have a table:

```
|eid   |ManagerID|Phone#|(other details..|
|------|---------|------|----------------|
|1001  |1004     |12345 |.........       |
|1002  |1004     |1233  |.........       |
|1003  |1006     |133   |.........       |
|1004  |         |444   |.........       |
|1005  |1004     |555   |.........       |
|1006  |         |666   |.........       |
```

and so on

I am trying to display all fields for the manager that is managing the highest number of employees.

I have

```
SELECT *
FROM EMPLOYEE 
GROUP BY Manager
HAVING COUNT (Manager)=(
SELECT MAX(theCount) AS theCount
FROM (
SELECT Manager, COUNT(Manager) theCount
FROM EMPLOYEE
GROUP BY Manager));
```

but keep getting error:

```
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

and i cant figure out why.

I know this part works to give a table with the counts of the managerIDs:

```
SELECT Manager, COUNT(Manager) 
AS theCount 
FROM EMPLOYEE 
GROUP BY Manager
```

Comment: what is your dbms?

Comment: Using Microsoft SSMS

Comment: Is this a recursive table (I mean, is `ManagerID` a foreign key to `eid`)? If so, how many layers of recursions do you support? Please [edit] your question to include [proper sample data](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) and expected results, and also the tag for the SQL Server version you're using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH managers AS (
SELECT
  ManagerID,
  count(eid) as directs_count
FROM employee
GROUP BY ManagerID
)
SELECT *
FROM employee
WHERE
  eid in (SELECT TOP 1 ManagerID FROM managers ORDER BY directs_count DESC)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below -

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=31c6b65b636be8640489a81616a82e62)**

```
select * from
(
select managerid,count(*) as cnt,row_number() over(order by count(*) desc)
as rn
from
employee where managerid is not null
group by managerid
)A where rn=1
```

OUTPUT:

```
managerid   cnt rn
1004         3  1
```

Comment: your using `count(*)` based on a group by that doesn't fit the text of the question...